# Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible on scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm new to CNN and building a sequential model from an example with the following structure

CNN structure 1: CONV1(16 (3*3))-Relu1-Maxpooling1(2*2)-Dropout1(0.25)-CONV2(32 (3*3))-Relu2-Maxpooling2(2*2)-Dropout2(0.25)-Dense(512)- Relu3-
Dropout3(0.5)-Output(Softmax)

The code is the following:

```
# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices.
# For example, for three classes, [0,0,1] -> 0, [0,1,0] -> 1, [1,0,0] -> 2 
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

# The data, split between train and test sets:
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

#building a CNN model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


# initiate RMSprop optimizer
opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)

# Let's train the model using RMSprop
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy', metrics.Precision(), metrics.Recall()])

# preprocessing data
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

# Normalization
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

start = time.time()

# Training
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          shuffle=True)

stop = time.time()

print(f"Training time: {stop - start}s")

# Testing
y_prediction = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
y_prediction_class = np.argmax(y_prediction, axis=1)

y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)

print("Confusion Matrix:\n", confusion_matrix(y_test, y_prediction_class))

print("Classification Report:\n", classification_report(y_test, y_prediction_class))

scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)

print('Test loss:', scores[0])
print('Test accuracy:', scores[1])
```

I'm getting an error in the line  `scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)`

I kind of know what it is complaining about but do not truly understand why it's complaining about it.

If I understand correctly, it's saying the size is not the same but I don't understand why it's not the same size.

I looked around in existing StackOverflow answers, and most solution is changing loss from "categorical_crossentropy" to "sparse_categorical_crossentropy". However, that gives me the following error

```
'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,10] and labels shape [320]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_34779]
```

So I don't think that's the correct solution.

Please push me in the right direction, I'm very confused.